# Designing a multimedia website for CD

Tags: web

I need to design a mini website to give to clients. The site includes mp3s and videos which must be played within the site itself and not use any 3rd party media players. Is Flash the only / best solution?

I also need to protect these files. Is there a way that I can stop users 'exploring' the CD and not get access to the content?

Answer (score 0):

Flash is a 3rd party component.

You might want to try experimenting with HTML 5 see the link below:

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp

This would make your websites functionality dependent on the browser the client is using.

It is unlikely you would be able to prevent users accessing the music files on the CD.  Possibly you could store the data on the CD in an encrypted format and make your own custom active x control that decrypts the data on the fly.  This would be difficult to do though.  Do you mind if I ask why you want to distribute your site on CD?  Why don't you just make a website and have user access control on it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. We alr4eady have a wensite for our services but cannot provide this to our clients clients due to the branding. We want to ofer a reselling opportunity so the purpose of the CD is to offer our services to the end client through a 3rd party without them going online [where the competition is much greater]. The key issue for us is providing an interactive CD where the user can select our suppliers, listen to them and watch video etc WITHOUT opening the content in an external media player. I've read that including a Flash Projector would get around the Flash requirement?

Comment: Apologies for the poor typing.

Comment: Flash Projector is used to make stand alone apps that play videos it is not useful for websites.  There is an HTML video tag you could use.